# UniqueKey in SOLR

Tags: solr

I'm using DIH to index my entities. I'm facing an issue while delta-import. I've declared multiple entities in one data-config.xml. The entities will have different primary key. Now if I want to delta-import how should I mention the UniqueKey in schema.xml.

My data-config structure is like this

```
<document>
  <entity></entity>
  <entity></entity>
  <entity></entity>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your uniqueKey field should be globally unique. If that requires creating a composite key with type and value - that's acceptable. You can keep your original keys separately as well and use deltaQuery (assuming SQL here) with that.

You can create a composite key either directly in DIH using Transformers or after DIH, using [UpdateRequestProcessor pipelines](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/).